# SELECT с условием

Tags: sql

Есть тако запрос
нужно чтоб условие применялось только для совпадения по полю field(значение field1), на совпадения по другим параметрам они не должны влиять(например по field2)

```
SELECT field, value FROM table
WHERE value NOT IN('value1','value2')
```

Помогите составить запрос

Comment: Невменяемо. Покажите на примере (данные в виде CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO скриптов и требуемый результат с пояснениями). И не забудьте указать СУБД, включая точную версию.

Answer (score 1):

не так просто понять ваш вопрос, но подозреваю так

```
WHERE  (field = 'field1' AND value NOT IN (..))
    OR (field <> 'field1')
```